# Preprocessor Macro Function that allows for GUI Library Expansion

Tags: c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am attempting to create a Preprocessor Macro Function that registers callback functions for my own GUI Library I am making. The library is designed to be easily expanded by 3rd parties by using the Macro function mentioned above.

**My Problem:** My macro function includes other preprocessor directives which I think are not allowed. I want to code my REGISTER_CUSTOM_CALLBACK_FUNCTION in a way that allows the user to create their own widgets and register their own callback function with the main GUI library. Any ideas how I can still achieve what I am trying to do?

```
#define FORWARD_DECLARE_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(callbackFunctName) Integer callbackFunctName(Draw_Box& window, Integer windowIndex, Integer id, Text cmd, Text msg);

#define REGISTER_CUSTOM_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(callbackFunctName) \
    #ifndef CUSTOM_CALLBACK_1 \
        #define CUSTOM_CALLBACK_1 \
        FORWARD_DECLARE_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(callbackFunctName) \
    #elif !defined CUSTOM_CALLBACK_2 \
        #define CUSTOM_CALLBACK_2  \
        FORWARD_DECLARE_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(callbackFunctName) \
    #endif

// Intended Usage: In a customers code they will be able to create their own 
// Widgets with their own Window Callback functions like this...
REGISTER_CUSTOM_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(progressBarCallback)

... some other code

REGISTER_CUSTOM_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(hyperlinkCallback)
```

Heres the main window callback that is called each clock step:

```
Integer main_callback(Draw_Box& window, Integer windowIndex, Integer id, Text cmd, Text msg)
{
    #ifdef CUSTOM_CALLBACK_1 
        CUSTOM_CALLBACK_1(window, windowIndex, id, cmd, msg); 
    #endif 
    #ifdef CUSTOM_CALLBACK_2 
        CUSTOM_CALLBACK_2(window, windowIndex, id, cmd, msg); 
    #endif 
}
```

**Any ideas how I could code my REGISTER_CUSTOM_CALLBACK_FUNCTION to allow the user to create their own widgets and register their own callback function with the main GUI library?**

Comment: The preprocessor usually only does one pass over the source, so you can't define a macro inside another macro.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes lol as I mentioned in my question and have heard numourous times today I know that. My question is there a way to achieve my intended outcome without these.

Comment: Why employ the preprocessor? Is there something wrong with regular plain C functions?

Comment: @n.m. No not at all but I am coding in 4dm which is a niche language that is very similar to C but doesn't allow code outside functions thus the need for pre-processor functions unless you know of a different way I can make my GUI library expandable?

Comment: Why don't simply use function pointers?

Comment: *If* that worked, both your macros would expand to identical *prototypes*, and then try to call the prototype. 
 You're probably still asking about "4dm"; if you are, `Get_function` looks promising, coupled with a (global) array of strings. But that language is quite underdocumented - it's far from obvious how to call such a function. I would start with figuring out how to do that.

Comment: Let the user place his code in a function then. Is there something that prevents that? The user should be able to initialize his widget library *somehow*.